# "zPosition" CABasicAnimation not working

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

I used an animation along the z axis a long time ago in Objective C :

```
    CABasicAnimation *positionAnimation;

    positionAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"zPosition"];
    positionAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:frandom(800, 400)];
    positionAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:frandom(-300, -100)];
    positionAnimation.duration=duration;
    positionAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    positionAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

But it is not working anymore on swift 3, the layer does not move at all.

```
        let positionAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "zPosition")
        positionAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: Float.random(from: 800, 400))
        positionAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: Float.random(from: -300, -100))
        positionAnimation.duration = duration
        positionAnimation.repeatCount = 400
        positionAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

Did i miss something ? 
thank you.

Comment: What’s the Swift code you are trying to write?

Comment: Just updated, please refresh. Sorry about that.

Comment: What are you expecting to see happen? Changing the `zPosition` does not cause visible motion. It just changes the layering order.

Comment: Well at the time i used it in objc the layers moved, it was maid for a star field, the star came from the center and moved along the z position...

Comment: I just try it, working on ObjC not in swift man